# DateTime.ToString from all formats to dd/MM/YYYY?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a simple routine which parses a `DateTime.Now` & performs a `.ToString()` on it to add it into a file name to be saved:

```
 DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
 string dateNow = timeNow.ToShortDateString();
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateNow, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);          
 string DateString = dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
 string fileName = string.Concat("MyArticle_" + region + "_" + DateString + fileExtension);
```

this is the resulting output string:

```
MyArticle_Africa_07-May-15.PNG
```

This is all good until I get a user on an American machine where the DateTime settings are different e.g.

05-07-15

In this case my `ParseExact()` method throws an exception as the input is not a valid date time. Is there a way to accommodate all date time inputs & parse to dd/MM/YYYY?

Comment: Why don't you use `String.Format` to create the string in one step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you don't need all these lines of code. You just need this:

```
 // We just have to pass to the ToString
 // method the exact format we want. Under the hood the CLR has
 // the know how to execute this command and you get the desired 
 // output.
 string DateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Furthermore, we use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method, when we want to get this exception you have mentioned. Saying this, I mean that we know that the string representation of dates, which we want to parse are of the exact format, we have specified in  `DateTime.ParseExact` and if some of them aren't we wan't to be informed know it. Usually, we would have a try catch clause and in the catch clause we log this.

Comment: Ok so ParseExact is used when we are expecting a certain DateTime format & we want an exception to be thrown & handle it if the format passed in is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

You need to try this:

```
string DateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
 string fileName = String.Concat("MyArticle_" + region + "_" + DateString +  fileExtension);
```

Comment: This is the solution what actually you was searching for @hardgraf

Comment: String.Concat is useless here as the string is already concatenated. Even better, use `String.Format` to create the final string with a single call and no temporary strings

Comment: So to get 07-May-15 I just used DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"). Looks like I was going round the houses.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to convert `DateTime.Now` to a string, you can create the entire string in one step using [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
var fileName = String.Format("MyArticle_{0}_{1:dd-MMM-yy}{2}",
                             region,DateTime.Now,fileExtension);
```

or

```
var fileName = String.Format(CurrentInfo.InvariantCulture,
                             "MyArticle_{0}_{1:dd-MMM-yy}{2}",
                             region,DateTime.Now,fileExtension);
```

to avoid internationalization issues.